# Make a file downloadable

Tags: php

So I am busy making a download page. 

On this download page, all the recently uploaded files will be shown on this page. 

Once they are shown, the files have to be **downloaded** by the `users`.

I inserted the path from which the files have to be downloaded (they are on a remote server) but it does not work, I get an error that the requested URL is not found.

How can I make it downloadable?

My PHP code:

```
<?php

//Connectiegegevens
$ftp_server = "myserver";
$ftp_user_name = "myuser";
$ftp_user_pass = "mypass";
$source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$destination_folder = "/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums";
$destination_file = $destination_folder . "/" . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// get contents of the current directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $destination_folder);

$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "$destination_folder");


   foreach ($contents as $mp3_url) { 
     $filename = basename($mp3_url, ".mp3");
?>
<br>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Programma</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo "<a href='$mp3_url'>$filename</a>"; ?></td>
   </tr>
</table>

<?php

 } 

?>
```

The files mp3 files. Also, do you guys know how to take away the dots I see when the files are displayed?

[image]

Comment: Of course it does not work, when you just link to the result of `basename` - that will leave the file name only, so all these relative URLs you are creating, will point to files on _your_ server, within the current directory. As I already told you when you asked this the first time - you need to create the proper, absolute HTTP URLs that refer to those files.

Comment: I asked you to give a code example as a answer so that I could accept it. I do not know how to do that. Please give a example

Comment: Just search how to create absolute url's

Comment: I am not going to drop everything and write code for people, just because they go “I don’t know how to do that” immediately. //  `/public_html/wp/wp-content/…` is not what you want to link to, because that is a file system path, on a different system no less. Assuming you don’t want to create FTP URLs (which would need a user name and password), you probably want to create the corresponding HTTP URLs that match those file system paths you got there. […]

Comment: […] So the `/public_html/` part likely needs to get replaced with something like `http://example.com/`, so that you get URLs like `http://example.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/somefile.mp3`. Figure out what the correct URL to create is, and then - create it. That is basic string manipulation, so if you lack knowledge regarding that, start by reading up on it.

Comment: ````http://example.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/somefile.mp3```` leads to a file that is downloaded. I want that all the files in the Albums folder is downloaded. So it should be without ````/somefile.mp3```` @CBroe

Comment: Also the url is wrong, my whole upload form dissapears when writing this, @CBroe

Comment: You can not just download all of those files at the same time, without extra steps. You can only download one file at a time - so if you want to download the content of a whole folder in one go, you would need to put all the files into some sort of archive / container format, like ZIP or TAR, first.

Comment: The path you mentioned is the path in which the files need to be uploaded to. It is in a remote ftp server. So ````http://example.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/somefile.mp3```` will not work since it has to be uploaded AND downloaded from that path. You cant upload a file to ````/albums/somefile.mp3```` @CBroe

Comment: You’re not making much sense here. Upload and download are two completely different things. It is totally unclear, how you think the two are even connected here.

Comment: _“Also the url is wrong, my whole upload form dissapears when writing this”_ - there _is_ no upload form anywhere in what you have shown us so far. And no one said you had to use the _same_ URL or path for both to begin with.

Comment: Oops, I ment to say my displayed files were gone. Spelling mistake. The $destination_file is the path to which the uploaded files are saved, yet you are telling me I should change it too: ````http://example.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/somefile.mp3```` @CBroe

Comment: _“is the path to which the uploaded files are saved”_ - you have not shown us where you are actually _saving/uploading_ anything to the remote FTP, the code you have shown does not contain that part. _“yet you are telling me I should change it”_ - no, I keep telling you that you should change the path you are trying to _download_ the files from, not where you are trying to upload them to. That you have both mangled together, without _properly_ explaining that to begin with, so that we can’t even properly tell what you are actually doing there, is on you.

Comment: Ok, sorry if I was not clear then. Let me explain; the files are uploaded to ````/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums```` where they are saved. The path from where the files are saved, is also the path from where they need to be retrieved and displayed. @CBroe

Comment: Do you want to _download_ your files via FTP? Then the users would have to supply FTP username and password after they clicked on such a link, or you would have to expose username and password directly in the HTML code you are creating there. Since you most likely _don’t_ want that, you probably want to download them via HTTP instead. And for that, again, you will need to determine the HTTP URL that _corresponds_ to the FTP path first of all.

Comment: Well, the first one I don't want to do. I tried to determine my HTTP URL that corresponds with the FTP path, doing what you told me. I wrote; https://radioprogrammabank.nl/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/22nl.mp3. But this will not work (either my content goes away or it failed. Could I just make a different variable called $download and put this path in there? @CBroe

Comment: Does somebody know how I can get rid of those dots @CBroe

Comment: Just skip the rest of your loop processing, if `$filename` is `.` or `..`

Comment: What do you mean with *Just skip the rest of your loop processing*? @CBroe

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: Hi @CBroe. I tried what you said, but for some reason the code echo's 1. Here is my code : ````foreach ($contents as $mp3_url) { 

    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $destination_folder);

    if($filename = "." && "..") {
    continue;

   }```` I cannot seem to find my mistake

Comment: Well for starters, you are _overwriting_ the variable you are looping over, inside of the loop … Why is `$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $destination_folder);` suddenly _inside_ the loop? The variable you are outputting and that _gives_ you these dots, is `$filename` … so check what _that_ contains.

Comment: @CBroe. I put the ````$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $destination_folder);```` outside of the loop. The ````$filename```` contains another variable called ````$mp3_url````. This variable has been renamed in the foreach. ````foreach ($contents as $mp3_url)````. ````$contents```` has the ````$destination_folder````. Which contains the path. It still returns 1.